# Different limiting donor in chemical reaction function

Tags: python, cheminformatics

I have couple of chemical reactions that are connected. Every reaction has one of 3 available donors, which are getting consumed so eventually they are 0  and when that happens reaction can't be executed.

So for example if concentration of donor B is small, and gets consumed in the first reaction, the third reaction can't get executed.

```
#Reactions look like that. 
#1. A + B -> C +  B_1 
#2. C + G -> D + G_1
#3. D + B -> E + B_1
#4. E + G -> F + G_1
#5. D + H -> J + H_1
```

which im reading them through excel.

```
  wb = open_workbook(reactions)
  ws = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
  n_rows = ws.nrows

  #number of reactions
  no_reactions = n_rows - 1

 components = []
 for i in range(1,n_rows):
    if ws.cell_value(i,reactant_location) not in components:
       components.append(ws.cell_value(i,reactant_location))
    if ws.cell_value(i,product_location) not in components:
       components.append(ws.cell_value(i,product_location))
    if ws.cell_value(i,donor_location) not in components:
       components.append(ws.cell_value(i,donor_location))

 def simple_equation_system(t,c):
    for i in range(1,no_reactions+1):
       cr = components.index(ws.cell_value(i,reactant_location))
       cd = components.index(ws.cell_value(i,donor_location))
       cp = components.index(ws.cell_value(i,product_location)
       r_r = 1 * c[cr] * c[cd]
       dcdt[cr] += -r_r
       dcdt[cp] += r_r
     return dcdt
```

I don't know how to input donor concentration and every time that donor is "B", the concentration of donor is subtracted by 1.  So for example if concentration of B is 1, then only first,second, fifth reaction can happen, but not the third and forth.

Maybe I need to do a for loop that goes through all donors and when it finds it, subtracts from the previous one.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but first, `k_r = 1` doesn't make sens, because it's always 1, you could just as well put `1` on the next line. Second, you should separate your logic from the fact that you are using excel: you should make a function(s) which read excel, and return back python objects, upon which you ll be working later

Comment: I know k_r = 1 doesn't make sense. I have different constants that are later subjects for regression. Wanted to simplify the code. Will change it so i doesn't confuse you. Second part I don't quite understand?

Comment: Consider the example: I would like to run your code on my laptop, but if I copy paste it, it won't work simply because I don't have your excel, in exactly same format etc.... If, however, you make your code work with simple python objects (list, dicts, etc..) I will be able to very easily run your code. If you want to use Excel, do it, but separate this excel handling from your main logic. At that point, it's very easy to understand your problem, and help you